# Accessing releated field

Tags: php, filemaker

In FileMaker I have (a.o.) two related tables, where `Betreuer_id` of table "studentpaper" refers to `id` of table "Betreuer".

[image: related tables]

With help of FileMaker's PHP API, I want to access a record in "studentpaper" including the releated fields. Howerver, the later poses a problem. Consider the following PHP code:

```
 $findCommand =& $fm->newFindAllCommand('studentpaper');
 $result = $findCommand->execute();
 $records = $result->getRecords();
 $record = $records[0];
 echo $record->getField('Titel'); // okay
 echo $record->getField('Betreuer_id'); // okay
 echo $record->getField('Betreuer::Name'); 
 // ERROR: get empty string, even related record has a non-empty field
```

I have expected for "Betreuer::Name" the correct related result, as usually in FileMaker (and as I get in studentpaper's layout). However, I get only an empty string. 
What am I doing wrong? Does the relation in FileMaker's PHP-API differs from the "usual" FileMaker approach?

Comment: database don't generally try to read your mind and realize you want related table information as well. You told it to fetch data from studentpaper, and you got information from studentpaper. It's not the db's fault that it couldn't tell you want information from betreuer as well.

Comment: I like your fast debian mirrors at tu.chemnitz (thx!) but hey!, the question is missing to describe what is exactly the problem or which error (message) you got. With 4k reps you should know that ;) German table names might also being hard to understand for the most of the readers.

Comment: You might want to know that *assigning the return value of 'new'* is deprecated in PHP 5. This is because all object variables are references. Therefore the `&` operator should being omitted in such cases: `$a =& new Class()`.. However, this will not fix your problem, just a hint.

Comment: @hek2mgl: Sorry, I have hidden it in the code. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @MarcB: I is not about "mind reading". The "::" constitutes the proper relation in FileMaker, e.g., in FileMaker script or at "layout" design.

Comment: Why is the question marked a "off topic"? It is a programming related question.

Comment: I marked it off-topic first because it looked first like one of those 1000, here is my db design, why is my code not working questions. They are off-topic. I retracted my close because you updated the question and the topic `filemaker` is relatively specific.. To the topic, I'm not an expert, but after following a short tutorial I would say you need to created the relationship in filemaker's GUI first.. Did you followed this tutorial (for example) : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFYxNOeAS1U ?

Comment: @hek2mgl: The relationship was established in the GUI. The show that, I've added the screenshot.

Comment: Normally a relationship in a (SQL) DB would not lead to a recursive fetch like you expect. This would be too *heavy* for the most operations. You would explicitly requesting such using a `JOIN` operation. I read (quick) read trough the FileMaker API specification and there is no JOIN operation mentioned. Therefore I expect that you need to create another view in file maker's GUI which will reflect this JOIN. Then in PHP use that view as your `$layout`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody is interested, I found the solution on my own.

The problem was that the field wasn't defined (in the layout) as normal text input, but as selection field resticted by a value list.

Thus, one needs to access the value not via the usual `getField` function but by one of the functions related to value lists. In my case, `getValueListTwoFields` did the job.